# gulp: how to replace the link to code and inserting code from file

Tags: gulp, gulp-plugin

how to replace the link in the *index.html*:

```
<link async rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css">
```

to code from *styles.min.css* file

```
<styles>
...
</styles>
```

which plug-in?
Thnx!

Comment: Looks like you are asking for a plugin to do some work for you. These type of questions are off-topic here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use [gulp-wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) if they are bower packages or [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) if they are your own css and js.